# Regular expression too permissive

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I'd like to describe a regular expression along the lines of:

```
not (a|the) foo
```

So `(a|the)` should appear That is it should match each of the following:

```
not foo
not a foo    
not the foo
```

where an arbitrary number of spaces could occur between words. But this phrase:

```
notfoo
```

Should not be matched. To this end, I made this regular expression:

```
r = re.compile('not[\s]*[a the]*[\s]+foo')
```

But `r` is too permissive, in particular it'll match any number of occurences of `[a the]`

I tried using `[a the]?` but then it does not match "the". How should I describe a regex matching zero or one occurences of a or the?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is it what you're looking for? square brackets [a the] mean that you're looking for either a, space, t, h, or e

```
r = re.compile('not(\s+a|\s+the)?\s+foo')
```

Answer (score 2):

You may use a regex with an optional group:

```
not(?:\s+(?:a|the))?\s+foo
   ^^             ^^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/lO3bVF/1)

**Breakdown**:

- `not` - a `not` word
- `(?:\s+(?:a|the))?` - one or zero (due to `?` quantifier) sequences of:

  - `\s+` - 1 or more whitespaces (if you use `*`, zero or more whitespaces will be matched)
  - `(?:a|the)` - either `a` or `the` character sequences
- `\s+` - 1 or more whitespaces
- `foo` - a `foo` word

Comment: Just FYI: since non-capturing groups are used in my expression, it will work well with `re.findall`, you won't have to use `re.finditer` to get the whole match (as e.g. with Marat's regex that uses *capturing* groups).

Answer (score 1):

```
r = re.compile('not[\s]*[a the]*[\s]+foo')
```

#### [] vs |

You're looking for the *whole* words "a" or "the". The `[`...`]` construct matches any of the letters in between the brackets so `[a the]*` would match `''`, `ah te`, `eehta`, and anything else you can think up that has one or more of those letters.

Instead of `[a the]*` you're looking for `(a|the)`.

If you'd like those words to be optional you can use `?` to match that group 0 or 1 times like this: `(a|the)?`

So you'll have:

```
r = re.compile('not[\s]*(a|the)?[\s]+foo')
```

You already have a `*` on the first spaces match to match 0 or more spaces and a `+` or the second to match 1 or more spaces.

#### spaces

One thing you probably don't want to match is `nota foo`. You could avoid that by adding spaces to the `(a|the)?` group: `([\s]a|[\s]the)?`:

```
r = re.compile('not[\s]*([\s]a|[\s]the)?[\s]+foo')
```

#### improvements

That may work for your needs but there are a couple other improvements you could make.

You could use `\b` to match word breaks around your words instead of worrying about the space before/after them (note that you'll need to be careful to use a raw string with the `r` prefix when using `\b`):

```
r = re.compile(r'not[\s]*\b(a|the)?[\s]+foo')
```

Note that you also don't need `[`...`]` around `\s`:

```
r = re.compile(r'not\s*\b(a|the)?\s+foo')
```